# hook_form_alter execution order

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

Is there a way to change the order of execution of hook_form_alter in Drupal 7 without changing a module's weight or hacking Drupal Core?

I am trying to alter the element added in [translation_form_node_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--translation--translation.module/function/translation_form_node_form_alter/8) from the translation module. When debugging the form I can't find the element so I assume my hook is being executed before the one in the translation module is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. `translation_form_node_form_alter()` implements `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` which I believe is called *after* `hook_form_alter()`, so even changing the module weight wouldn't be enough. I think your two options are to use a `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` and ensure you have a high enough module weight, or use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` (if possible).

Comment: hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() IS called after hook_form_alter()

Comment: Solved it using hook_form_form_id_alter and module weight.

Comment: @Bart if you used `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` then my understanding is that you shouldn't need to modify the weight at all (because all `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` calls are made after all `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`).

Comment: @Andy, it doesn't seem to work if I use foo_form_page_node_form_alter without adjusting the weight.

Comment: @Andy, hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter fires after hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and before hook_form_alter(), see the [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8).

Comment: @Bart I was looking at the source to give you those details - check out the bottom of [`drupal_prepare_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form) and [`drupal_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7). I'd already noticed that the docs seemed off, so I [created an issue](http://drupal.org/node/1229868). Dunno why it doesn't work for you without altering the system weight tho!

Answer (score 18):

Also worth mentioning, there is a new drupal 7 API called [hook_module_implements_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) which lets you alter the execution order for a given hook WIHOUT altering the module weights table.

Sample code from the API docs showing how easy this is to do:

```
<?php
function hook_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'rdf_mapping') {
    // Move my_module_rdf_mapping() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['my_module'];
    unset($implementations['my_module']);
    $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I was able to execute my hook last with this exact code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to make sure your hook_form_alter is called after another modules hook_form_alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // do your stuff
}

/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 *
 * Make sure that our form alter is called AFTER the same hook provided in xxx
 */
function my_module_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    // Move my_module_rdf_mapping() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['my_module'];
    unset($implementations['my_module']);
    $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
  }
}
```

This also works when the other module has provided a form_alter hook in the variation: hook_form_FORM_ID_alter. (they explain that in the documentation: [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)).

I know that this post is quite similar to wiifm's post, but thought it useful with an example with hook_form_alter

Comment: Didn't work for me.