# In hook_node_insert drupal_goto with alias name not working

Tags: 7, nodes, path-aliases

In hook_node_insert() i have used drupal_goto(), to go to the newly created node with alias name of it, but id doesn't work.

**I have already created url alias with patterns for that content type.**

```
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
drupal_goto($alias);
```

If i give drupal_goto() with nid it works.

```
drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid);
```

What is the issue with respect to alias name not working or how to get alias of newly created node and get it redirected to view page of it with alias name as url.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**[Updated code]**

This is the code which i am trying

```
function hook_node_insert($node)
{
    if($node->type == 'product')
    {

        $_SESSION['product_node_nid'] = $node->nid;
        $banner = $_SESSION['banner'];
        $theme = $_SESSION['theme'];
        $params = array();
        $params['node'] = $node;
        $site_email = variable_get('site_mail', '');                
        if(($banner || $theme) || ($banner && $theme)) {
            drupal_goto('payment-approval');
        }
        else {
            //$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
            module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto'); // include the inc file for Pathauto module
            pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', 'node/'.$node->nid, array('node' => $node), $node->type, $language->language); // Language is optional
            $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
            //$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid); print_r($alias); exit();
            drupal_goto($alias);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the circumstances that would require this, exactly? The default action after submitting the node add form is already to redirect to the new node. Use drupal_goto() with care in hooks; it can interfere with cron runs if it ever gets executed by cron.

Comment: As LesLim said, there is default functionality of `node` module to redirect to `node/[nid]` when new node be save. What you want to achieve with your code, its not clear. Please update the complete scenario, so you will find the correct solution.

Comment: [Updated code] is the one which i am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third variable for `module_load_include()` function is missing in your code.

You should use code `module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto');`
instead of `module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');`

There is another method for your problem that you can use `hook_form_alter` instead of `hook_node_insert` hook in your module.

`hook_node_insert` will execute if you will insert node using any other method like importing node using `feeds` module.

**Update Code:**

```
function custom_feature_node_insert($node) {

  $options = array('language' => pathauto_entity_language('node', $node));

  //$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
  module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto'); // include the inc file for Pathauto module

  pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', 'node/'.$node->nid, array('node' => $node), $node->type, $options['language']); // Language is optional
  $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);

  drupal_goto($alias);

}
```

Comment: tried this one module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto'); instead of module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto'); still it is redirecting to node/nid not alias name

Comment: @Ram, Have you checked `$alias` in your function before `drupal_goto()` function.

Comment: this is wat print_r($alias) is printing node/212

Comment: @Ram, it mean `pathauto_create_alias()` function is not working in your condition.

Comment: pathauto_create_alias() first parameter module i can give module only know ??? i gave node is tat correct rite ? then wats the issue?

Comment: @Ram, I have updated answer with working code.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the drupal_goto and found out that you must provide the path for parameter. You can't use alias for drupal_goto. So i think you can solve your problem like that:

1. While you create node. You will also create the alias for that node. The reference for create the alias for node [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/create-path-alias-programatically-when-node-is-created). In your code just normally redirect like that

   ```
   drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid);
   ```
2. After that you will install [Global redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. This module will have responsibility to redirect your node/nid to your node's alias

**[Updated]**

Can you try to generate the alias by using the [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto). So can you put these code in hook_insert()

```
function yourmodule_node_insert($node){
  module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
  pathauto_cleanstring($node->title);
  $node->path = array('pathauto' => TRUE );
  drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid);
}
```

Comment: Tried installing Global redirect module, gave like this drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid);still redirects to node/nid only

Comment: in hook_node_insert will node alias will get created or is it after tat only is the question.Because its only redirecting with node/nid.

Comment: module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto'); 
pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', 'node/'.$node->nid, array('node' => $node), $node->type, $language->language); 
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid);
drupal_goto($alias);

Still it goes to node/nid only.

Comment: Can you check the alias is created or not $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid); print_r($alias); exit();

Comment: Its printing node/207 this only. Not alias name

Comment: Hi! Please check my update and give a try

Comment: still its going to node/nid only.

Comment: In hook_node_insert in if condition i am sending the node after hook_node_insert to payment form and completing the form, then i redirect to drupal_goto('node/'.$nid), but it goes with alias name properly as expected and in  else condition i am trying to redirect to drupal_goto() with alias name , but its redirecting to node/nid. wat i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

drupal_get_path_alias() expects a full internal Drupal path, like this:

```
drupal_get_path_alias('node/23');
```

However, you're only giving it an NID, which is being evaluated like this:

```
drupal_get_path_alias(23);
```

Comment: See my updated question. i tried like that, it still goes like this only node/nid

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm guessing you're using Pathauto, which also uses hook_node_insert() to generate the URL path for the node. Your hook is probably running before Pathauto does its work.

Comment: You can adjust your module's weight to ensure that it runs its hooks after Pathauto, or you can implement hook_module_implements_alter() to change the execution order for a particular hook: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9720/23553