# How do I set 'Locale settings' fieldset, in the user profile form, to uncollapsible?

Tags: users

After running a `dpm($form)` via `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` I couldn't see the 'Local settings' in the form defintion of the user profile form. I did a search for 'locale settings' on all the code and found the value I need to alter (I think) on line 2016 of `system.module`. So I tried:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['timezone']['#collapsible'] == FALSE;
}
```

Cleared the cache. Fieldset is still collapsible?

Comment: Which version of drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. The error thrown is: Undefined index: timezone. I don't know what to alter. system.module alters the form on line 1967.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
The point is that your hook_form_alter is called before system_form_alter, so you don't see the timezone. You need to reorder the implementation of hooks with [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)

Here is the full code:

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['CUSTOM_MODULE'];
    unset($implementations['CUSTOM_MODULE']);
    $implementations['CUSTOM_MODULE'] = $group;
  }
}

function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['timezone']['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
}
```

Credits to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9720/8865).

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't precisely answer the question, but I just used this by itself in my theme's template.php with no problem:

```
function MY_THEME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['timezone']['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
}
```